# version control system - migrating from visible systems razor

Tags: svn, version-control, version

We are using visible systems razor now for many years as version control system. Now with Windows XP dying out and razor not supporting any up-to-date Linux or Windows system we are thinking about migrating to another VCS (best would be SVN).

We use a lot of branching in Razor. I am afraid that this will not be easy to import into SVN (Especially the handling of Threads in Razor).

Does anybody have any experience here?

Does anybody else have the problem with the need (MUST) to migrate visible razor to an up-to-date OS?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why don't you keep your older source's history in Visible Razor and start with brand-new Subversion repository from the scratch? I see this as the only possible solution. Not aware of any tested Razor > SVN migration tools or approaches.

Comment: I think that it will be hard to migrate to subversion as we make heavy use of the "Threads" functionality of visible razor. This allows you to create a "SW release tree" by choosing the correct (branched) version of each source file and saving this information in a "Thread". This way you can store the source code for several platforms, that differ in only a few files, inside the same system. I know that branching works in subversion, but am not sure, if this is easy to handle in case that branching files is a think that is heavily used to compile for different platforms.

Comment: branching will perfectly work but you need to learn about SVN and it's common patterns. Reading SVNBook is the good start! http://svnbook.red-bean.com/

Comment: thanks, i read through the book (quickly), but as far as i understand it is not exactly the same. in visible razor you can have the same trunk, only branching a few of the files to fit to another platform (e.g. support for different peripherals). nevertheless all other files (except of the single 1 that was branched) are automatically kept from Trunk. In Subversion as far as i understood i always need to branch (copy) my complete Trunk. There is no chance to mix Trunk / branch in 1 working copym correct?